# Can I use a single pipeline for both a file receive location and an email receive location?

Tags: biztalk, pop3

I have a pipeline that is working for a file receive location. This pipeline accepts a csv file and maps it to an XML.

I'm now trying to setup a new email receive location using the same port, pipeline and pipeline settings.

Shouldn't biztalk ignore everything but the attachment if I set the body part index equal to 2? And then it should place the attachment in the pipeline just like with the file location, then the pipeline would output an XML file.

Error:

> Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.PersistenceException: Exception occurred when persisting state to the database. ---> Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.PersistenceItemException: A batch item failed persistence Item-ID 72fbeba9-6bfe-48e0-a0e6-ca5bbd191aa1 OperationType MAIO_CommitBatch Status -1061151998 ErrorInfo The published message could not be routed because no subscribers were found. . ---> Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.PublishMessageException: Failed to publish (send) a message in the batch. This is usually because there is no one expecting to receive this message. The error was The published message could not be routed because no subscribers were found. with status -1061151998

Pop3 properties:

[image: Pop3 Properties]

PipelineConfigurations:

[image: Pipeline Config1]
[image: Pipeline Config2]
I tried stopping the orchestration and the send port and test both locations.

Testing the email location I got the same error with an email with a .csv attachment.

Testing the file location the data didn't reach the database, but the csv was processed because I could see it in the information logs.

This leads me to the conclusion that the problem is related with the mime decoding and whatever my pipeline is outputing from the email body parts.

Also after researching for a while all solutions seem to point to the necessity of having a pipeline exclusively for email since I need to say which part of the multibody part to decode. I was hoping there was a solution that would allow me to reuse the pipeline I use for the file location.

Comment: It is not failing in the pipeline.  It is failing due to there being no Orchestration or Send Port that is expecting the message the Receive Port has published to message box.

Comment: Part 2 is set as the body part, but other parts still exist. So it depends on what your pipeline does really.

Comment: This error comes from an Orchestration.  Nothing to do with a Pipeline.

Comment: @Johns-305 I did some tests and I figured that it can't be a problem with the orchestration. If I disable the orchestration I still get the same error testing the email receive location and I get no error testing the file location

Comment: @Ruud How do I take advantage of the MIME decoder to only process the attachment and drop the rest?

Comment: Can you show us your pipeline settings?

Comment: @AntonioCraveiro **Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.PersistenceItemException** - Only an Orchestration can produce this message.  A Pipeline cannot produce this message.

Comment: @Ruud I've added the pipeline configuration settings, but I basically copied them from the file receive location that was already working

Comment: @AntonioCraveiro Sorry, I goofed up, the settings don't say that much. Maybe the code behind the pipeline routes the wrong parts (without the necessary context) but that's grasping at straws a bit. oɔɯǝɹ's answer below should put you in the right direction anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As @Dijkgraaf mentioned:

> It is not failing in the pipeline. It is failing due to there being no Orchestration or Send Port that is expecting the message the Receive Port has published to message box.

That means that the receive worked, that the message has passed the pipeline, and is published in the Messagebox, but there is no matching subscription.

Check for routing failures in the BizTalk management console to find out why. It may be that the message type is not waht you expected, or that one more published properties are not set correctly.

Comment: Not related to the problem specifically but it might help me figure out the problem. Do you know why if I stop the orchestration the file location that was already set up and is working doesn't give the same error?

Answer (score 0):

See the suspended message and check which body part is the CSV file. Your config says its it should be the 3rd message BodyPart = 2.